Search for a general solution for a hyperbolic equation with a boundary condition on a sphere
I need help solving an interesting problem on partial differential equations. I got stuck with the problem of finding a general solution to the equation $$u_{xy} + u_{xz} + u_{yz} = 0$$ with a boundary condition $u|_{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1} = 0$.
The equation has a hyperbolic type with eigenvalues $-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, 1$. For hyperbolic equations, as far as I know, there is no maximum modulus principle, but it seems to me that the solution in this problem will be zero. I also tried to switch to spherical coordinates and solve the problem using the Fourier method, but nothing good came of it. Therefore, if someone knows how to solve this problem, I will be grateful for your help.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Your boundary condition suggests that you should rotate to another coordinate system such as
$$\begin{cases} x = \frac{u\pm v \pm w}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \vdots\end{cases}$$
etc, for $y$ and $z$, such that
$$x^2+y^2+z^2= u^2+v^2+w^2$$
From this coordinate system, your choice of spherical coordinates will be more obvious as the differential equation will simplify. Can you complete the solution to the differential equation now?

I tried to switch to the "canonical" coordinate system
$$
\begin{cases}
x = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} u -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} w\
y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} u +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} w\
z = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} w
\end{cases}
$$
in which our equation will take the form $u_{uu} + u_{vv} - 2 u_{ww} = 0$. The boundary condition will be rewritten as $u|_{u^2 + v^2 + w^2 + uv = 1} = 0$. But I still have difficulties with the transition and further solution. Could you give me a one more hint?

@TomSawyer the boundary condition should not have changed. That means you haven't followed my hint exactly, as I said you need to choose a rotation, i.e. $x^2+y^2+z^2=u^2+v^2+w^2$
